# How can i compare an element from ICollectionView with a string

Tags: c#

I have collection of element and I want to compare a string with one of the element from that collection.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets measurements collection.
        /// </summary>
        public ICollectionView Measurements
        {
            get { return measurements; }

            set { measurements = value; }
        }
```

I have try to do this assert but i cant compare the element:

```
string searchObject1 = "Measurement1";
Assert.AreEqual(searchObject1, measurementViewModel.Measurements.CurrentItem);
```

I think i need a cast before `measurementViewModel.Measurements.CurrentItem` have anyone an idea how can I compare an element from that collection with a string?

Comment: What about `CurrentItem.ToString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do like this

```
 string searchObject1 = "Measurement1";
    Assert.AreEqual(true, String.Compare(searchObject1, 
measurementViewModel.Measurements.CurrentItem.ToString(), false)==0);
```

or

```
 string searchObject1 = "Measurement1";
    Assert.AreEqual(0, String.Compare(searchObject1, 
measurementViewModel.Measurements.CurrentItem.ToString(), false));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Assert.AreEqual` will (eventually) check by calling `object.Equals`. Actually as `CurrentItem` is of type `object` this check is doing a reference-check instead which apparently is NOT true.

If you´re after the value of the current item stringify it:

```
Assert.AreEqual(searchObject1, measurementViewModel.Measurements.CurrentItem.ToString())
```